# HTML data-attribute not accepting child html class and other attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes, custom-data-attribute

when I working with data attribute, it's accept regular html tag. But not accepting child classes. For example, look at my first code;

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <a href="#" class="mi-tooltip" data-tooltip="<h1>MIUI_Tooltips is a lightweight.</h1><p>Around 5KB minified </p><u>and offering</u> a wide range <i>of configuration options.</i> <br><br><button> A Button </button>">condimentum</a>.Eros natoque.</p>
```

It's working good, because I'va added here just regular html tag. But when I add class and value inside data-****** attribute, its not working. Look at the second code;

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <a href="#" class="mi-tooltip" data-tooltip="<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/8726372/pexels-photo-8726372.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260" width="100%" class="my-image"/><h1>MIUI_Tooltips is a lightweight.</h1><p>Around 5KB minified </p><u>and offering</u>">condimentum</a>.Eros natoque.</p>
```

How can I add images, classes, links and other attributes inside one data-atrributes HTML Tag ?

Comment: you need to escape your quotes

Comment: @Pete If I escape my quotes, How can I use / add classes, ids, url ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have to replace `"` with `&quot;`

```js
document.querySelector('a').dataset.tooltip = '<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/8726372/pexels-photo-8726372.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260" width="100%" class="my-image"/><h1>MIUI_Tooltips is a lightweight.</h1><p>Around 5KB minified </p><u>and offering</u>'

console.log(document.querySelector('a').outerHTML)

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', document.querySelector('a').dataset.tooltip)
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum <a href="#" class="mi-tooltip">condimentum</a>.Eros natoque.</p>
```

> ```
> <a href="#" class="mi-tooltip" data-tooltip="<img src=&quot;https://images.pexels.com/photos/8726372/pexels-photo-8726372.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1260&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; class=&quot;my-image&quot;/><h1>MIUI_Tooltips is a lightweight.</h1><p>Around 5KB minified </p><u>and offering</u>">condimentum</a>
> ```

I guess that `'` would also be fine:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum <a href="#" class="mi-tooltip" data-tooltip="<img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/8726372/pexels-photo-8726372.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260' width='100%' class='my-image'/><h1>MIUI_Tooltips is a lightweight.</h1><p>Around 5KB minified </p><u>and offering</u>">condimentum</a>.Eros natoque.</p>
```

Comment: @Konard Many Many Thanks, but it it possible to use double qoutation anyway...?

I see that, single quotation working well. Though I'm asking you that, is there any way to use double quotation without any problem....?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @AsmaBintaYounus probably not, because html parser won't know where the attribute ends

Comment: @Konard Ok, so as theres I've used a class for image  " class='my-image' "..... Can I select this class without adding  .my-image property name in css stylesheet...?

I want to use it like that way    .any-div img   or   .any-div>img     ........

Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't quite get it. What do you mean by *select*? The string in `data-` attribute is not in the dom tree until you add it

Comment: @Konard..... Oh.. I see... Thats mean for designing the tag inside data-attribute, I need to add a class or ID and then by declaring the class name in css stylesheet, I can Design it...

Comment: @Konard Is it possible to design any HTML tag inside of data-attribute without adding a class name or ID ?